Python(Pandas) Change all values in dataframe column from other rows
I am currently working on a Dataframe which contains data about products, there are products which are regular products, some are variable products and the third kind are the variations of the latter. The product variations currently have no category information but there is a "Parent" column which points to the "SKU" of the parent product. The Dataframe has a structure similar to this:
Dataframe example
For instance product "Product 2" or "AV002" by "SKU" is a variable product with a category of "Audio and Video", product "Product 2 V" or "AV002A" by "SKU" is a variation of the product with no category info. I am trying to get a copy the "Category" information from "Product 2" to "Product 2 V" with the "Parent" column connecting them both. Iterating through the Dataframe and getting the information would be an easy task but for some other technical problem I need to modify the Dataframe with comprehensions.
So far I've tried .loc .query .where (probably the wrong way) to try and find the data but I always get a Dataframe full of Nan IE:
1639    NaN
1640    NaN
1641    NaN
1642    NaN

My python code is:
def get_data():
    fields = ['ID', 'SKU', 'Name', 'Category', 'Type', 'Parent']
    data = pd.read_csv('input/products.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
    #I need to write something here to get it done
    #Dataframe is used on other functions when returned
    return data

To be clear, after running the script I would like the Dataframe to be like this:
This is what I want to achieve
Some of the things I've tried:
data['Category']=data.where(data['Parent']==data['SKU'])['Category']

Result: No change in DataFrame
data['Category']=data.loc[data['Parent']==data['SKU']]['Category']

Result: No change in DataFrame
data['Category']=data[data['Parent']==data['SKU']]['Category']

Result: No change in DataFrame
I've also tried using a copy of the Dataframe:
    data = pd.read_csv('input/products.csv')
    data_copy = pd.read_csv('input/products.csv') 
    data['Category']=data[data_copy['SKU']==data['Parent']]['Category']


Result: No change in DataFrame
About another 20 tests with no success, I've tried alternating the order of "SKU" "Parent" and the original Dataframe and the copy.
The products with category data should stay unchanged. I am pretty sure the solution to this is pretty obvious and simple but I have been unable to find it, sorry if it's been answered already.
Thanks in advance for any insights into this problem.
Edit added data that's representative of what I can access(CSV ,, signifies a new row)
ID,SKU,Name,Category,Parent,Type,,
382,CE001,Product 1,Consumer Electronics,,Simple,,
231,AV002,Product 2,Audio and Video,,Variable,,
562,AV002A,Product 2 Variation,,GFP001A,Variation,,
763,GFP002,Product X,Cleaning supplies,,Variable,,
745,GFP002A,Product X Blue,,GFP002,Variation,,
123,GFP002B,Product X XXL,,GFP002,Variation,,
The real data has the same structure
File link (not sure if it's allowed)
https://jmp.sh/s/IBvOod64TQVzWBfiM8lI

For clarification, are you trying to replicate a join/lookup? If so, what you want is a left or inner join via pandas.merge.

I'm not really sure if that's what I need to do, as I am really new to Pandas. I need that rows with information in the "Parent" and no information on the "Category" get the info from the corresponding product (searching it via the "SKU" column). I'll look the pandas.merge function to try and implement what I need. I'll keep posting until it's fixed.

Can you show a representative sample of your input data and the desired results after processing (please - no screenshots, just copy/paste actual data). This will help clarify what your goal is.

Done, added the data as requested(edit at the bottom of the original question). Thank you both for your responses. Still checking if pandas.merge will work for me.

The logic is not clear, do you want to use the parent column or the SKU prefix to make the matches?

This is a bit of a messy solution, but you could just trial mapping the values from one column first, then the second it the first fails.  This answer is making the assumption that the product variations are named consistently enough to slice the parent's root-name from the variant's.
For example:
#  demo slicing the last word from a string
s = 'Product 2 Variation'
s[:(s.rfind(' '))]

output:
'Product 2'
#  Save copy for testing
data = df.copy()

#  Create dictionary keys = SKU, values = Category where Category is not empty
sku_cat_map = df.loc[df['Category'] != ''].set_index('SKU')['Category'].to_dict()
sku_cat_map

Output:
{'CE001': 'Consumer Electronics',
'AV002': 'Audio and Video',
'GFP002': 'Cleaning supplies'}.
#  Create dictionary keys =  Name, values = Category where Category is not empty
name_cat_map = df.loc[df['Category'] != ''].set_index('Name')['Category'].to_dict()
name_cat_map

Ouput:
{'Product 1': 'Consumer Electronics',
'Product 2': 'Audio and Video',
'Product X': 'Cleaning supplies'}
# Isolate the rows where Category is empty
variations = df.loc[df['Parent'] != '']

#  Map the Parent values to the Category values
variations['Category'] = variations['Parent'].map(sku_cat_map)

#  Fill the empty Category values with the Parent values
df.update(variations)
df

Output:




ID
SKU
Name
Category
Type
Parent




0
382
CE001
Product 1
Consumer Electronics
Simple



1
231
AV002
Product 2
Audio and Video
Variable



2
562
AV002A
Product 2 Variation

Variation
GFP001A


3
763
GFP002
Product X
Cleaning supplies
Variable



4
745
GFP002A
Product X Blue
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002


5
123
GFP002B
Product X XXL
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002



# Find remaining rows with empty Category values
remaining = df.loc[df['Category'] == '']

# Split last word from Name, and map it to the Category
remaining['Category'] = remaining['Name'].apply(lambda x: name_cat_map[x[:(x.rfind(' '))]])

#  Fill the empty Category values with the Parent values
df.update(remaining)
df


Output:




ID
SKU
Name
Category
Type
Parent




0
382
CE001
Product 1
Consumer Electronics
Simple



1
231
AV002
Product 2
Audio and Video
Variable



2
562
AV002A
Product 2 Variation
Audio and Video
Variation
GFP001A


3
763
GFP002
Product X
Cleaning supplies
Variable



4
745
GFP002A
Product X Blue
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002


5
123
GFP002B
Product X XXL
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002



# Complete the function:
def create_df():
    fields = ['ID', 'SKU', 'Name', 'Category', 'Type', 'Parent']
    data = pd.read_csv('input/products.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
    return data


def get_data(df= None):
    df = create_df() if df is None else df
    df = df.copy()

    sku_cat_map = df.loc[df['Category'] != ''].set_index('SKU')['Category'].to_dict()
    name_cat_map = df.loc[df['Category'] != ''].set_index('Name')['Category'].to_dict()

    variations = df.loc[df['Parent'] != '']
    variations['Category'] = variations['Parent'].map(sku_cat_map)
    df.update(variations)

    remaining = df.loc[df['Category'] == '']
    remaining['Category'] = remaining['Name'].apply(lambda x: name_cat_map[x[:(x.rfind(' '))]])
    df.update(remaining)
    return df

# Test the function
print('Data before function call')
display(data)
print('Data after function call')
display(get_data(data))

Output:
Data before function call




ID
SKU
Name
Category
Type
Parent




0
382
CE001
Product 1
Consumer Electronics
Simple



1
231
AV002
Product 2
Audio and Video
Variable



2
562
AV002A
Product 2 Variation

Variation
GFP001A


3
763
GFP002
Product X
Cleaning supplies
Variable



4
745
GFP002A
Product X Blue

Variation
GFP002


5
123
GFP002B
Product X XXL

Variation
GFP002



Data after function call




ID
SKU
Name
Category
Type
Parent




0
382
CE001
Product 1
Consumer Electronics
Simple



1
231
AV002
Product 2
Audio and Video
Variable



2
562
AV002A
Product 2 Variation
Audio and Video
Variation
GFP001A


3
763
GFP002
Product X
Cleaning supplies
Variable



4
745
GFP002A
Product X Blue
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002


5
123
GFP002B
Product X XXL
Cleaning supplies
Variation
GFP002




Still trying to understand your response,but it seems to do exactly what I want. I'll check back in a while and mark the question as answered if it works on a full scale test. Thank you

Yep, this was EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Time to study the code. Thank you for the help!

Hey RaulZ!  Sorry I never checked back for comments sooner!  Did it end up making sense?  Is there something I could do to help or should explain a little better?

Nope, everything worked as intended with some minor tweaks.Thanks for the help!
